# Verification for the proof of $\forall\mathcal{H}, |\mathcal{H}_C|\le |{B\subseteq C: \mathcal{H}\text{ shatters }B}|$

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

The following is my proof of the following claim in the construction of Sauer's lemma, which is quite different from the solution in the book where I found it, but I'm not sure I've made any mistake:

**Claim:**
For any set $C = \lbrace c_{1},...,c_{m} \rbrace$, let $\mathcal{H}$ be some set of binary functions from some superset $\mathcal{X}$ of $C$ to $\lbrace 0, 1\rbrace$ and denote by $\mathcal{H}_C$ the restriction of $\mathcal{H}$ to $C$, then we have:

$$|\mathcal{H}_C|\le |\lbrace B\subseteq C: \mathcal{H}\text{ shatters }B\rbrace |.$$

**Proof**:

To prove the claim, we will prove the following proposition:

**Proposition:**
Suppose the class of sets $\mathcal{C}$ that shatters $k$ distinct non-empty sets $A_1, A_2,..., A_k$, where $k$ is a non-negative integer, then $\forall c\in\mathcal{C}$, $\mathcal{C}\backslash c$ will shatters at least $k-1$ sets that are chosen from $k$ shattered sets of $\mathcal{C}$, that is chosen from $\lbrace A_1, A_2,..., A_k\rbrace$.

**Proof of the proposition:**
For $i\in[1, k]$, denote the power set of $A_i$ by $\mathcal{P}(A_i)$, from the definition of a shattered set we have that:

$$
\begin{align}
&\forall a\in \mathcal{P}(A_i)\rightarrow\exists c\in \mathcal{C}: a=c\cap A_i
\end{align}
$$

If there's only one shattered set amongst all shattered sets of $\mathcal{C}$, $A_i$ for some positive integer $i\le k$, such that $\exists a\in\mathcal{P}(A_i): a=c\cap\mathcal{P}(A_i)$, then it's easy to show that the proposition is true since $\mathcal{C}\backslash c$ still shatters all $\mathcal{C}$'s other shatter sets $A_j$ for $j\ne i$.

Now suppose that there're at least two different shattered sets of $\mathcal{C}$, $A_p$ and $A_q$ such that $(a_l\in\mathcal{P}(A_l)) = c\cap A_l$ for $l\in\lbrace p, q\rbrace$. Without the loss of generality suppose that: $a_1=c\cap A_1, a_2=c\cap A_2$ where $a_1\in\mathcal{P}(A_1)$ and $a_2\in\mathcal{P}(A_2)$.

We now show that in this case, there exists some $(c'\in\mathcal{C})\ne c$ such that $a_1=c'\cap A_1$ or $a_2=c'\cap A_2$. And if this is true, then the shattered sets of $\mathcal{C}\backslash c$ will at most 1 element behind the shattered sets of $\mathcal{C}$.

Assume to the contrary that there does not exist any such element $c'$. Since $\mathcal{C}$ shatters both $A_1$ and $A_2$, we have that $\mathcal{P}(A_l) = \mathcal{C}|_{A_l}$ for $l\in[1, 2]$. This shows that $c\in \lbrace A_1, A_2\rbrace$, because otherwise we can simple choose some $c' \in \mathcal{C}$ such that $a_1\subseteq c'$ and $(c'\backslash a_1)\cap A_1 = \varnothing$ and so $a_1 = c'\cap A_1$ (contrary to our assumption). However, if $c\in \lbrace A_1, A_2\rbrace$, for example if $c=A_1$, then clearly $a_2=c\cap A_2 = A_1\cap A_2 = (A_1\cap A_2)\cap A_2$. But this implies that we can replace $c$ by $(A_1\cap A_2)\ne A_1$ since $A_1\ne A_2$ (a contradiction with the assumption that $c$ can't be replaced by other element in $\mathcal{C}$). Which concludes the proof of the proposition.

Back to the proof of the claim. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the set of all functions from $C\to \lbrace 0, 1\rbrace$. We can see that $\mathcal{F}$ shatters all the sets that are subsets of $C$. Equivalently:

$$\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{P}(C).$$

Moreover, $\mathcal{P}(C)$ consists of all subsets of $C$ that are shattered by $\mathcal{F}$. Therefore, $|\mathcal{F}|=2^{m}=|\mathcal{P}(C)|$ satisfies the inequality in the claim.

Clearly, we can obtain $\mathcal{H}_C$ from $\mathcal{F}$ by removing each element in $\mathcal{F} \backslash \mathcal{H}_C$ at a time. After each removal, we obtain a new set whose shattered sets contains all elements of the previous set's shattered sets except, probably 1 set removed. This implies that regardless of how many elements $\mathcal{F}\backslash \mathcal{H}_C$ contains, after every removal we always have: $|\mathcal{H}_C|\le |\lbrace B\subseteq C: \mathcal{H}\text{ shatters }B\rbrace |.
\square$

Comment: @AnneBauval that's true. I've fixed the typo.

Comment: Does your Proposition mean "Suppose $\mathcal{C}$ is a class of sets that shatters $k$ distinct non-empty sets $A_1, A_2,\dots A_k$, where $k>0$, then $\forall c\in\mathcal{C}$, $\mathcal{C}\setminus\{c\}$ will shatter at least $k-1$ sets among $A_1,\dots,A_k$"?

Comment: denote the *power* set of $A_i$
 by $P(A_i)$

Comment: from the definition of a shattered set we have that:
$$\forall a\in \mathcal{P}(A_i)\;\exists c\in \mathcal{C}: a=c\cap\color{red}{A_i}
$$ And the sentence after that line is really weird.

Comment: @AnneBauval Based on your feedback, I've updated related mistyped or unclear parts.